# Merging LR states to form sets for LALR Grammar Parsing

Tags: context-free-grammar, lalr

If suppose I have the following states:

`I1: S->TaV.,$`

`T -> V.,a`

`I2: T -> V.,a|$`

will I merge these states?

Basically, I want to know what is the core of I1. Is {**S->TaV**. , **T->V.**} the core of I1 or will I say that I1 contains two cores - **S->TaV** & **T->V**?

Dragonbook says that for each core present among the sets of LR(1) items, find all sets having that core, and replace it by their union.

Now, if {**S->TaV**. , **T->V.**} is the core of I1, then I won't merge the sets.
But, for the core **T->V.**, both I1 and I2 contain the core and hence must replace by their union.

So should I merge the sets or not?

some background details that might be useful:

the original grammar to start off with was

`G: S->TaV | T`

`T->V | b`

`V->Ta | c`

Answer (score 1):

An LALR(1) parser generator does not literally merge states.  It checks to see if a newly created state has already has been created.  It compares the new state to all the other states  by comparing the core items.  If the core items are identical (same number of items and same items) then the newly created state is discarded and the transition should go to the old state.

An LALR(1) parser generator builds an LR(0) state machine and does not care about look-aheads during the state construction process.  All it cares about are the item sets.  So the answer is NO, these two states should not be merged, because I1 has 2 core items and I2 has 1 core item.

The idea of merging states applies to minimal LR(1) state construction which is a more complex process than LR(0) state construction.

This is an LALR grammar analysis problem, not grammar parsing.